# Configure java-endpoint to receive multiple outbound messages

Tags: java, workflowoutboundmessage

we are currently trying to receive multiple different OutboundMessages through a java webservice (One for Account, one for Opportunity). We are using the generated WSDL files for the endpoints. 
Eclipse IDE can easily create a webservice for a single WSDL file. The service name is "NotificationService" as defined by the WSDL. When trying to import the second WSDL as well, there is a naming conflict because the second service is also named "NotificationService". Is it possible to change that name **besides** changing the WSDL file by hand?